# I have Filter in Java that redirect fin but navigator don't cached imaged ( png and jpg but not gif)

Tags: java, http, caching, filter, http-status-code-301

i have a java server applications and nginx server with images , the idea is that images url in java Server redirect to nginx server with filter Java. 
i use filter java with 301 status and redirect to ngix image location but with the idea that navigator cached image and with F5 or refresh page , the navigator don't return to query http server java or nginx, but yes return for java Server responde again 301 and nginx responds 304. 
The test result that gifs dont return at press F5 o refresh the page , but with png and jpg return and return and return.

any idea??

the results is in the images:
[image]
and nginx:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error with filter its me thanks!!
The f5 or enter in url bar cause imagen revalidación is for this that dont cache. Then The problem is code fails st only caché jpg and dont png. Now works

Comment: Please elaborate. How did you solve the problem exactly ?